# Spring Boot calling rest ws SocketTimeoutException connect timed out

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, timeout, moxy

I have developed a spring boot application, this app simply makes web service calls to another system. I have thousands of web service call tasks(Callable or supplier). Thats why I send 40 tasks per second in parallel. Target system that I send requests to has enough resource to handle thousands of request.When I start to send requests everything is fine but after a while I realize that from time to time my spring boot app get **java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out**

Target system is a rest web service, I used **moxy** implementation of **JAXB** in my Spring boot app while calling this target ws

Pls help me about this socket connect timeout, is there any configüration that I have to know about high volume web service call on spring boot app(embeded Tomcat)

Here is the exception full stacktrace :

````
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:287)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$0(JerseyInvocation.java:753)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.dt_access$570(JerseyInvocation.java)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:229)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:414)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:752)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:445)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:351)
    at com.cvk.pricing.cache.client.pricing.BrandedFareServiceClient.shoppingSearch(BrandedFareServiceClient.java:62)
    at com.cvk.pricing.cache.task.BrandedFareSearchTask.get(BrandedFareSearchTask.java:53)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceTask.doLeaf(ReduceOps.java:747)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceTask.doLeaf(ReduceOps.java:721)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractTask.compute(AbstractTask.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.writeTo(MOXyJsonProvider.java:959)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:251)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1135)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.doWriteEntity(ClientRequest.java:516)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:384)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:282)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:278)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred marshalling the object
Internal Exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.writeTo(MOXyJsonProvider.java:957)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-25003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred marshalling the object
Internal Exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException.marshalException(XMLMarshalException.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.JSONWriterRecord$OutputStreamOutput.write(JSONWriterRecord.java:1016)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.JSONWriterRecord$OutputStreamOutput.writeLocalName(JSONWriterRecord.java:1083)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.JSONWriterRecord.writeKey(JSONWriterRecord.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.JSONWriterRecord.openStartElement(JSONWriterRecord.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.JSONWriterRecord.attribute(JSONWriterRecord.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLDirectMappingNodeValue.marshalSingleValue(XMLDirectMappingNodeValue.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLDirectMappingNodeValue.marshal(XMLDirectMappingNodeValue.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.ObjectMarshalContext.marshal(ObjectMarshalContext.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.marshal(XPathNode.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathObjectBuilder.marshalAttributes(XPathObjectBuilder.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.marshalAttributes(TreeObjectBuilder.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.startElement(XPathNode.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.marshalSingleValue(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.marshal(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.ObjectMarshalContext.marshal(ObjectMarshalContext.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.marshal(XPathNode.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathObjectBuilder.buildRow(XPathObjectBuilder.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.marshalSingleValue(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.marshal(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.ObjectMarshalContext.marshal(ObjectMarshalContext.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.marshal(XPathNode.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathObjectBuilder.buildRow(XPathObjectBuilder.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeObjectMappingNodeValue.marshalSingleValue(XMLCompositeObjectMappingNodeValue.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeObjectMappingNodeValue.marshal(XMLCompositeObjectMappingNodeValue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.ObjectMarshalContext.marshal(ObjectMarshalContext.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.marshal(XPathNode.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathObjectBuilder.buildRow(XPathObjectBuilder.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshalStreamOrWriter(XMLMarshaller.java:1147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:934)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:877)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:496)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1291)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.lambda$_apply$0(HttpUrlConnector.java:382)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.dt_access$717(HttpUrlConnector.java)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableOutputStream.write(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.JSONWriterRecord$OutputStreamOutput.write(JSONWriterRecord.java:1009)
    ... 76 more```
````

Answer (score 0):

Increase maxThreads on other tomcat [executor](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/executor.html)

Comment: Do u mean target web service side by "other Tomcat" ?

Comment: Yes, if "another system" runned on tomcat.

Comment: It runs on weblogic and it is a web application(not Springboot app)

Comment: General sense is that the server does not have time to respond quickly enough to your requests and you need to increase the limit of incoming requests, or speed up the execution of requests